# How to open phone gallery or camera or any other medium available using ImagePicker in Flutter.?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need some help regarding the image picker plugin in flutter. I want to let users select images from wherever he/she wants like a camera, gallery, Google drive/photos, or anywhere else not just only one option.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  File _pickedImage;

  void _pickImage() async {
    final pickedImageFile =
        await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = File(pickedImageFile.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundImage:
              _pickedImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage) : null,
        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          onPressed: _pickImage,
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Add Image'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a rework of your `_pickedImage` to show an alert dialog so the user can choose the source of its image.

```dart
void _pickedImage() {
  showDialog<ImageSource>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      content: Text('Choose image source'),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Camera'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.camera),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Gallery'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.gallery),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ).then((ImageSource? source) async {
    if (source == null) return;

    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
    if (pickedFile == null) return;

    setState(() => _pickedImage = File(pickedFile.path));
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little problem here. the image picked by camera source is only being passed not the gallery image. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Using getX**

```
class UserImagePickerController extends GetxController {
  Rx<File> pickedImage = File('').obs;

  Future<void> pickImage({required BuildContext context}) async {
    await showDialog<ImageSource>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(content: Text("Choose image source"), actions: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Camera"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.camera),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Gallery"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, ImageSource.gallery),
        ),
      ]),
    ).then((ImageSource? source) async {
      if (source != null) {
        final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
        pickedImage.value = File(pickedFile?.path ?? '');
        logger.f(pickedFile);
        update();
      }
    });
  }
}
```